# The color of a selected slice in a chart

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

i’ve been working with the **ShinobiChart** trial version and I would like to know if there is a way to disable the **highlight** effect when you select a slice of the chart and it changes the color.

I readed the documentation and i changed the colors in the `flavourColors` array, i even changed to `NO` the value on `showCrust`.

```
pieSeries.style.showCrust = NO;

[[pieSeries style] setFlavourColors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: blue, green, yellow, pink, purple, gray, red, nil]];
```

There are two pictures about the **hightlight** effect i'm talking about.

[image: color-1]

[image: color-2]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `style` property on the `SChartPieSeries` object, there is also a `selectedStyle`. These are both of the same type - so you'll find the highlighted colours in the `flavourColors` array in the `selectedStyle` object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me sir, Thanks! and btw, nice job with the iOS8 Day-by-Day series! I learned a lot...